# Should i rely on PhPMyAdmin's table normalizing tool or do i carry out the changes myself?

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin

Full disclosure:

1. The images themselves are in spanish, i want to bring attention to the design only so i'm not modifying the former.
2. This may or may not be part of an actual information system that may or may not be accepted as my final project proposal in college next semester.
3. I created a number of UML diagrams to help me visualize segments of the information system (and also because reason 2).

The database doesn't exist in MySQL as of now, it has only been designed graphically through Excel and Visio. I began with an ER diagram that grew gradually throughout the days (see image below).

[image: mmkmkm]

(Image above) Following that, i created the tables in Excel and gave them attributes, which i eventually normalized.

[image]

After going through a number of UML diagrams, i created the class diagram.
[image]

As a result of the perspective gained from each step, i had to go back and fix any previously unnoticed mistake. Now that i have installed PhPMyAdmin through XAMPP, i'm able to create the database one by one. The thing is, all these junction tables make me wonder if the system would create them on its own after telling it to normalize them or if i should do it myself to be absolutely certain of the state of my database.

Which brings me here, what do you recommend?

Comment: To critique a schema, I need to see the main queries that are applied to it.

Comment: What are the Fact table and the Dimension tables?